# Prestashop Error:-in /hosting/www/pomeraniakids.com/public/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Hello i'm getting this error on my website.

> Notice: Undefined index: currencyRate in
>   /hosting/www/pomeraniakids.com/public/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 51 Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   /hosting/www/pomeraniakids.com/public/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 51

Can anybody tell me how to remove this error from pretsashop. Please.

Answer (score 0):

### What causes the issue?

In `.tpl` files of the theme you are using or in `.tpl` files of modules you have installed there is a variable `$currencyRate` which is not defined.

### How to fix it?

1. First of all you must be sure you have currencies defined properly in the backoffice.

   [image: Currencies in the backoffice]
2. If you have installed a non-default theme you can search for the variable `$currencyRate` in `.tpl` files in `themes/[your-theme]/` folder.

   Or in `modules/[any-installed-module]/` folder of installed modules.

   To prevent from the error you can add an `if` statement around this variable in `.tpl` file like this:

   ```
   {if isset($currencyRate)}

       {* the else code with $currencyRate variable ... *}

   {/if}
   ```